# Java SimpleXml parsing @ElementList

Tags: java, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I have this part from an Xml file:

```
<image height="55">image1.jpg</image>
<image height="60">image2.jpg</image>
<image height="170">image3.jpg</image>
```

I know that I can parse it with :

```
@ElementList(entry = "image", inline = true)
private List<Image> images;
```

but I need in my java object one attribute with the name :

```
String image; // correspond to image2.jpg
```

How can I do this with annotation ?

**Update:**

It's not that I want, I have a class like this.
But I want to declare only one attribute

```
String image;
```

to access directly to the text from the second line with direct annotation

```
<image height="60">image2.jpg</image>
```

for example (I don't know) something like this :

```
@Element(name="image[1]/text")
String image;
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Use @Text like this

```
class Image {

@Attribute
int height;

@Text
String image
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and looked so long. Thank you.